# LaTeX mode: How to select "pdflatex" instead of "latex" for a file automatically?

Tags: latex, customize, tex

I have a LaTeX file using lots of PDF figures (mostly because converting figures to EPS is a waste of disk space), so it requires to use `pdflatex`.

I added these lines to the end of my main file:

```
%% Local Variables:
%% latex-run-command: pdflatex
%% End:
```

Whenever when I open the file, Emacs asks me whether to evaluate these settings, and I confirm.
However, `C-c C-f` still runs `latex \\nonstopmode\\input input.tex`.

**Why doesn't it work?** (this is the question I should point out clearly)

Also in Customize the setting of `latex-run-command` still is `Standard`.

After a significant waste of time, I wrote a Makefile that builds my document (keeping the PDF open in evince). So I use `compile` to build the file now.

**Details:**

When I run `C-c C-f`, the output starts like this:

```
latex \\nonstopmode\\input Farbe.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (preloaded format=latex)
```

When I run `pdflatex` manually, the output starts like this:

```
pdflatex Farbe
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
```

So the preloaded format is different, causing errors like

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in RGB-Cube-3D.pdf (no Bounding
Box).
```

Also, using `latex-run-command: "pdflatex"` makes no difference: `pdflatex` is not being used.

**More details:**

When I load the file (having changed the settings to the following)

```
%% Local Variables:
%% latex-run-command: "pdflatex"
%% End:
```

and then do `C-h v latex-run-command`, I get:

```
latex-run-command’s value is "pdflatex"
Original value was "latex"
Local in buffer Farbe.tex; global value is "latex"

  This variable’s value is file-local.
  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Command used to run LaTeX subjob.
LaTeX Mode sets ‘tex-command’ to this string.
See the documentation of that variable.
```

But still, the command run is *not* `pdflatex`, but `latex`!

**More info** (2019-11-28)

My Emacs is 25.3.1, and in `loaddefs.el` I have:

```
(defvar latex-run-command (purecopy "latex") "\
Command used to run LaTeX subjob.
LaTeX Mode sets `tex-command' to this string.
See the documentation of that variable.")
```

And tex-mode.el contains:

```
(setq-local tex-command latex-run-command)
```

Even when I tried this, it did nor work:

```
%% Local Variables:
%% latex--command: "pdflatex"
%% eval: (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook (lambda () \
%%  (setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")))
%% End:
```

I also had tried variants `setq-local`, `tex-command` instead of `latex-run-command`, but it all did not work.

Neither does it work after having used `set-variable` interactively to set `latex-run-command`, nor does it work after I had set the variable in "*Customize Option: Latex Run Command*".

Comment: @Drew: Please just read the whole question, especially the part about "C-c C-f". Actually I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I tried a tex file of mine with `emacs -Q` and your local variables. After `C-c C-f` it does say `$ latex \\nonstopmode\\input tvFellerprobe.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex)`. Is it the same for you or not, when starting the things with `emacs -Q`

Comment: @andrej: Yes, it's the same. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: Have you tried `auctex`? It is a much richer mode than the native latex mode and might have something to accommodate your needs.

Comment: @NickD: Actually I'm happy with the Makefile (using `pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction nonstopmode`), but still I was curious why the setting won't work. Maybe someone else has an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I provided the answer: the mode function which sets `tex-command` from `latex-run-command` runs before the latter is given its file-local value.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is the syntax: the value is a string so you need to say so by surrounding it with double quotes. However I could not get this to work with the `latex-run-command` variable. However `tex-command` seems to work (for some value of "work"):

```
%% Local Variables:
%% tex-command: "pdflatex"
%% End:
```

EDIT: The problem with `latex-run-command` may be a sequencing problem: when the file is opened, does the mode function get run and then local vars are set? or the other way round? If the mode function is run first, that would explain why the `latex-run-comand` setting is ineffective: the mode function does

```
(setq-local tex-command latex-run-command)
```

so it is probably setting it to the old value, before the local variable setting takes effect. You can try customizing `latex-run-command` and restarting emacs: I suspect that that would work.

Comment: However customize says for `latex-run-command`: "LaTeX Mode sets ‘tex-command’ to this string."

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Consider the above as a possible workaround.

Comment: Maybe not a bug: see my EDIT.

Comment: On "*You can try customizing latex-run-command and restarting emacs*": That was not the question: I want to select LaTeX mode for a particular file, not for all LaTeX files.

Comment: And I was trying to explain (possibly: I may be wrong, but it's the only thing that I could think of that would explain the situation) why file local variables might not be able to do the trick.

Comment: ... or rather you cannot do it by setting `latex-run-command` locally in the file. As I demonstrated above, you can set `tex-command` locally: that works fine.

Comment: As I don't want to set it globally, I still wonder *why* it does not work. I mean the commands are executed. While debugging I noticed that the messages shown when loading the file (`The local variables list...** latex-run-command : "pdflatex"`) is not logged in `*Messages*`.

Comment: @U.Windl this does look like a bug in latex-mode. Nick's solution works for me: setting `tex-command` as your local variable, rather than `latex-run-command`. `latex-mode` uses `the value of `latex-run-command` to set the value of `tex-command`, but it is doing this *before* you load your file, and so by the time you set your local value to `latex-run-command` it's too late to do anything useful.

Comment: Funny thing: When I try to set `tex-command` interactively, the only completion is `tex--command`. Same thing happens when I try Customize. However when I use `describe-variable`, it completes to `tex-command`. I think I'll make a bug report for the Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not match the implementation, or the implementation is broken:
The variable `latex-run-command` was changed from `"latex"` to `"pdflatex"`, but command `tex-file` (found in `latex-mode-map`) still uses `latex \\nonstopmode\\input`.

Comment: I filed a bug report here: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1158035